# Issue (NPE) during deserializing a JSon messages while consuming

Tags: json, apache-kafka

Using a Java, Spring Boot, Kafka application I am trying to produce a Json message to a topic on Kafka and then trying to consume it. I am able to produce message and can see it on Confluent but while consuming it I am getting a NullPointerException as below -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonDesreializer..deserialize(KafkaJsonDeserializer.java:74) ~[kafka-json-serializer-5.5.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1365) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
```

I am using below serializer and deserializer -

**In producer -**

```
props.put("key.serializer", org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class );
props.put("value.serializer", io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonSerializer.class );
```

**In Consumer -**

```
props.put("key.deserializer", org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class );
props.put("value.deserializer", io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonDeserializer.class );
```

What I could be doing wrong here? Is providing a schema mandatory?

Comment: Can you show the actual message that was produced? If you don't have a schema, then use the Spring or Kafka built-in JSON serializer, not the one from Confluent

Comment: @OneCricketeer
 Yes, after using JsonSerializer it worked fine. So it means to use confluent serializer schema is required?

Comment: `JSONSchema` is required, yes. The built-in JSONSerializer with Kafka can still use a `schema` and `payload` field, mentioned here https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/